# Way to make AJAX page without hash fragments?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, google-crawlers

I have been exploring documentations to make AJAX generated content crawlable:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

What I don't get is, a lot of places they have mentioned "Pages without hash fragments". How does URL for AJAX pages without hash fragments work/look like ?

Is that something desirable to use or hash fragments is the right way to go about with it ?

**EDIT:** Seems what I was looking for is HTML 5 history API.

Answer (score 0):

Hash fragments are a way to support the back button. They are not necessary to make calls to webservices.

Comment: I have a single html page, which dynamically gets populated with some data through ajax calls depending on an id after #. What's the other way to do this if not hash ?

Comment: are you using a routing framework? Those use hashtags quite often.

Comment: I am using angularjs.

Comment: So angular uses a routing framework. Here's how to use it:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

You don't need any of this to do AJAX however.